# Java 2D array rectangle error

Tags: java

I have an addition to a question I asked earlier. I have a 2D array that I need to get the magnitude of each element based on the 4 surrounding elements. Surrounding being up, down, left and right. If one or more of the surrounding elements goes out of the array bounds, i.e. the current element is on an edge, it treats the out of bounds element as the current. My program only works when the array is a square, 4 x 4, 5 x 5, ect. but when it is a rectagle, 4 x 5, 5 x 6, ect I get an error. I believe this is due to the fact that array.length is no longer the same for x and y. I do not know how to correct this error, any help would be appreciated! This is my current code:

```
public class ArrayTest 
{ 


public static int[][] buildE(int[][] array)
{

    int [][] arrayE = new int[array.length][array.length];

    int up; 
    int down; 
    int left;
    int right; 

    for (int y = 0; y < array.length; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < array[y].length; x++)
        {

            //if element is on the top left
            if (y == 0 && x == 0)
            {

                up = array[y][x];
                down = array[y + 1][x];
                left = array[y][x];
                right = array[y][x + 1];

            }

            //if element is on bottom right
            else if (y == array.length - 1 && x == array.length - 1)
            {

                up = array[y - 1][x];
                down = array[y][x];
                left = array[y][x - 1];
                right = array[y][x];

            }

            //if element is on top right
            else if(y == 0 && x == array.length - 1)
            {

                up = array[y][x];
                down = array[y + 1][x];
                left = array[y][x - 1];
                right = array[y][x];

            }

            //if element is on bottom left
            else if (y == array.length - 1 && x == 0)
            {

                up = array[y - 1][x];
                down = array[y][x];
                left = array[y][x];
                right = array[y][x + 1];

            }

            //if element is on top 
            else if (y == 0) 
            { 

                up = array[y][x];
                down = array[y + 1][x];
                left = array[y][x - 1];
                right = array[y][x + 1];

            }  

            //if element is on left
            else if (x == 0)
            {

                up = array[y - 1][x];
                down = array[y + 1][x];
                left = array[y][x];
                right = array[y][x + 1];

            }

            //if element is on bottom
            else if(y == array.length - 1)
            {

                up = array[y - 1][x];
                down = array[y][x];
                left = array[y][x - 1];
                right = array[y][x + 1];

            }

            //if element is on right
            else if (x == array.length - 1)
            {

                up = array[y - 1][x];
                down = array[y + 1][x];
                left = array[y][x - 1];
                right = array[y][x];

            }

            //if element is not on an edge 
            else
            {

                up = array[y - 1][x];
                down = array[y + 1][x];
                left = array[y][x - 1];
                right = array[y][x + 1];    

            }

            int element = array[y][x];
            int magnitude = Math.abs(element - up) + Math.abs(element - down) + Math.abs(element - left) + Math.abs(element - right);

            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("#####################################");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Array Element: " + array[y][x]);
            System.out.println("Up: " + up);
            System.out.println("Down: " + down);
            System.out.println("Left: " + left);
            System.out.println("Right: " + right);
            System.out.println("Magnitude: " + magnitude);
            System.out.println("X: " + x);
            System.out.println("Y: " + y);
            System.out.println("Array Length: " + array.length);


            arrayE[y][x] = magnitude;
        }
    }

    return arrayE;

}


public static void outputArray(int[][] array)
{

    for(int row = 0; row < array.length; row ++)
    {

        for (int column = 0; column < array[row].length; column++)
            System.out.printf("%d ", array[row][column]);
        System.out.println();

    }


}

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    int [][] myArray = {{1, 12, 13, 14, 15}, {2, 22, 23, 24, 25}, {3, 32, 33, 34, 35}, {4, 42, 43, 44, 45}, {5, 52, 53, 54, 55}, {6, 62, 63, 64, 65}};

    outputArray(myArray);
    outputArray(buildE(myArray));

}

}
```

Comment: and the error you are getting is...?

Comment: are you sure all this code is necessary?

Comment: *"I have an addition to a question I asked earlier."*  Given no sentence in that ends with '?' prompts me to ask..  What is your ***current*** question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130538/java-2d-array-out-of-bounds-error

That is the question I had earlier and it was answered, now I am getting an array out of bounds error when trying to run this code with a "rectangle" 2D array. And this code is  necessary for the test I am using. This is all for a bigger program that I am writing. It has been a while since I've dealt with 2D arrays so I wanted to make a test code

Comment: @rsay3 by the way, don't include debugging code in what you paste here. It just makes your code longer which makes people less willing to read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your problem is that you are using `array.length` for both of your indices. You should use `array[0].length` for your `y` coordinate. You do this in a number of places, that's why it doesn't work for rectangles.

However, you would be far better served to take an OO approach to this kind of problem. Try this:

```
public class ArrayTest {
    public static enum Direction {
       LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN, SELF;

       public int getValue(int[][] array, int yIndex, int xIndex) {
           switch(this) {
               case LEFT:
                   if (xIndex == 0) return array[yIndex][xIndex];
                   return array[yIndex][xIndex - 1];
               case RIGHT:
                   if (xIndex == array[yIndex].length - 1) return array[yIndex][xIndex];
                   return array[yIndex][xIndex + 1];
               case UP:
                   if (yIndex == 0) return array[yIndex][xIndex];
                   return array[yIndex - 1][xIndex];
               case DOWN:
                   if (yIndex == array.length - 1) return array[yIndex][xIndex];
                   return array[yIndex + 1][xIndex];
               default:
                   return array[yIndex][xIndex];
           }
       }
   }

    public static int[][] buildE(int[][] array) {
        int [][] arrayE = new int[array.length][array[0].length];

        for (int y = 0; y < array.length; y++) {
            System.out.println("y = " + y);
            for (int x = 0; x < array[y].length; x++) {
                arrayE[y][x] = 0;
                for (Direction d : Direction.values()) {
                    arrayE[y][x] += d.getValue(array, y, x);
                }
            }
        }

        return arrayE;
    }

    public static void outputArray(int[][] array) {
        for(int row = 0; row < array.length; row ++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < array[row].length; column++)
                System.out.printf("%d ", array[row][column]);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [][] myArray = {{1, 12, 13, 14, 15}, {2, 22, 23, 24, 25}, {3, 32, 33, 34, 35}, {4, 42, 43, 44, 45}, {5, 52, 53, 54, 55}, {6, 62, 63, 64, 65}};

        outputArray(myArray);
        outputArray(buildE(myArray));
    }
}
```

Do you see how letting the objects do the work for you eliminates a lot of copy-paste code and if statements? Teach an object how to do a job, then say `MyObject.doJob()` instead of having your master object do the job. Delegate!